# Application gets freezed on Load Android?

Tags: android, performance

Hi I Created application of images and working fine. However there is small bugs which have come up. One is that when application icon is clicked on Launcher it freezes and turns screen black sometimes. But sometimes it loads fast and properly. It happens randomly.

So when it loads normally or freezes app and turns black before load I see GC running how to prevent this behaviour.

I have defined my application which extends Application class so call after Application before launcher activity freezes screen.

Following is my code in Application:

```
public class WallieApplication extends Application implements WallieConstants,
        WallieParseConstants, WallieSharedPreferencesConstant {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        try {
            super.onCreate();
            /**
             * Call to enable Local Data Storage.
             */
            Log.i("Debug", "Enable Local Datastore Parse");
            Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
            Log.i("Debug", "Initialize Parse");
            Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), PARSE_APPLICATION_ID,
                    PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);

            try {
                Crashlytics.start(this);
                Helpshift.install(this, HELPSHIFT_API_KEY, HELPSHIFT_DOMAIN,
                        HELPSHIFT_APP_ID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Crashlytics.log(e.getMessage());
            }
            Log.i("Debug", "Enable Push Callback");

            PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(),
                    HomeScreenActivity.class);
            Log.i("Debug", "Enable Push Callback Done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crashlytics.log(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

What i see is when i close application i see logs in this code printed on logcat. If they are printed i observed it freezes app?

Comment: can you please post code your startup activity ?

Comment: To track i put logs and i saw Activity onCReate is not being yet called. But screen freezes black on icon press in launcher

Comment: Have you check on device or emulator ?

Comment: on Device. I have also check when i close my app the code inside my Application class which extends Main Application class of Android executes and when i open it freezes

Comment: added code in onCreate of my application class not activity class

Comment: what is PushService and Parse if it such task which taken time then put those code in Services may be those creating problem for execution.

Comment: No it works fine normally. I told you that when application is close this code runs again and when i try to open app it freezes

Comment: @vo12 Any progress? Did you find what the issue was?

Comment: @Alex.Fwhat i did was deleted cache of application on application exit it worked fine on device tested and few more devices but still on some device it freezes so i put cache delete on start of app as well but i dont want to delete cache as next time app launches i read images from cache for faster loading but for now using your workaround only though it doesnt fully solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Look at the time consuming tasks you have in your `OnCreate` and other activity lifecycle methods that execute before the activity appears and move all the time consuming code to a background thread as an async task for example

Comment: To track i put logs and i saw Activity onCReate is not being yet called. But screen freezes black on icon press in launcher

Comment: added code in onCreate of my application class not activity class

Comment: Yes this can obviously hurt the loading time if there are any time consuming tasks executed on the UI thread

Comment: @AlexF but it doesnt consume this much time everytime. Its random. So with code its fine. I dont know whats exactly causing the problem.

Comment: I doubt anything is "random" it's probably that some things remain in cache. Try clearing app data and then take a look at how long that takes.

Comment: cleared application data on application exit. Lets see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do to much work on the UI thread. This can cause diffrent behaviors, depending on the device. To check if this is the problem you are faceing, take a look at this article:

http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html

Probably it's because you load a lot of images at the startup. You have to load them async to avoid problems like this. There are plenty of libraries helping you, i.e. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: My code in application executes on closing app from minimize screen. That time if you open app it freezes

Comment: Then I guess you have to add the code to your question.

Comment: added code in onCreate of my application class not activity class